# How to check if String ends with something from a list. C#

Tags: c#, list, ends-with

I want to take a user's input, and check if the end of what they put in ends with something. But it's more than one string. I have it in a list. And I could check if the input ends with a string from the list one by one. However, I would just like to check if the input ends with anything from a list.

Comment: If the answer I provided below worked for you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 42):

If "endings" is a List<string> that contains the possible endings to match:

```
if (endings.Any(x => userInput.EndsWith(x)))
{
    // the string ends with something in the list
}
```

Comment: is correct.  if (endings.Any(userInput.EndsWith)) also works with less code.

Comment: Using this method you can ignore the case / use invariant culture etc which is useful: `endings.Any(x => userInput.EndsWith(x, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] imageEndsWith = { ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG", ".jpg", ".JPG" };
if (imageEndsWith.Any(x => _fileName.EndsWith(x))) {
    //your code goes here
}
else {
}
```

what this code does is create an array of string(imageEndsWith) any of which you want to find at the end of another string(_fileName).

## For example This code will find the jpeg or jpg or png images when the name of file is in the variable _fileName

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: what this code does is create an array of string(imageEndsWith) any of which you want to find at the end of another string(_fileName).
For example This code will find the jpeg or png images when the name if file is in the variable _fileName